# Horizontally auto populate a row after selecting an option on a drop down list on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm sorry if this a simple and already answered question but I can't make work [any of the answers](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/M9m_SW8IdIs) I have tried ([this one too](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/_Kctrc3se9w)).

I'm trying to auto fill or auto populate a row with data from another sheet. I have this list with a named range Food on column A:
[image]

What I need to do is that when I select any of the on the other sheet the Protein, Fat an Carbs fields get auto completed. 
[image]

In this case, using Validation I can only select an option but don't know how to horizontally complete to the right with the data of the first table.

[This is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR64JFzeu4CJDGE8wc4B7U-gubdxieAdmod6GpTkwejexO8uqKtMVLjkL2HMC_X8v2yZNfFah4DKkM2/pubhtml)

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Dish` is in Sheet1 A1.
Assuming `Food` is in Sheet2 A1.

In Sheet1 C3 and copied down to suit:

```
=query(Sheet2!A:D,"select B,C,D where A='"&B3&"'",0)
```